# connect instance to ECS cluster by user data script in launch template is not functioning properly

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, launch-template

I have specific user data script which connect my instance to ecs cluster, weirdly it doesn't work unless I connect to the instance and manually stop and then start ecs service on it once again. After that it works completely fine.

user data script:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

sudo amazon-linux-extras disable docker
sudo amazon-linux-extras install -y ecs
echo ECS_CLUSTER=ClusterName | sudo tee -a /etc/ecs/ecs.config
echo ECS_ENABLE_GPU_SUPPORT=true | sudo tee -a /etc/ecs/ecs.config
sudo systemctl enable --now ecs
```

adding

```bash
sudo systemctl stop ecs
sudo systemctl start ecs
```

at the end didn't help, but when I do it manually after logging in to the instance it does help.

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/aws/amazon-ecs-agent/issues/1707

adding `--no-block` helped:

```
systemctl enable --now --no-block ecs.service
```